# Connecting an R script to shiny to output an image

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app GUI to allow for "easy" input of four data files into my R script. I want to be able to upload four files, choose options from two sets of radio buttons, and click "Submit" to run the chosen analyses. The final output (as generated in my analysis code) should be a .PNG file that will (a) be automatically downloaded to the working directory and (b) presented on the MainPanel of the GUI. To get an idea of what I'm trying to do, I've included the code for the UI of the app.

```
library(shiny)
  ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Pando Nutrition Microbiome Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId="n1","Shared Table Upload", multiple = FALSE),
      fileInput(inputId="n2", "Taxonomy File Upload", multiple=FALSE),
      fileInput(inputId="n3", "Meta Table Upload", multiple=FALSE),
      fileInput(inputId='ZHtree', "Phylogenetic Tree"),
      radioButtons(inputId="Selection1", "Select One",
               c("Fungi" = "ITS",
                 "Bacteria" = "16S")),
  radioButtons(inputId="Selection2", "Select Analysis",
               c("Shannon Diversity (Timecourse)" = "shannon1",
                 "Shannon Diversity (CTL vs EXP)"="shannon2",
                 "Top 20 Genera"="Top20Genera",
                 "Top 10 Genera"="Top10Genera",
                 "Top 5 Genera"="Top5Genera",
                 "Top 2 Genera"="Top2Genera"
                 )),
  actionButton(inputId="Submit", "Submit"),
  hr()
),
mainPanel(
  imageOutput("figure_1.png")
)
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

here is the R code that generates a 16s, "shannon1" plot in R Studio:

```
n1<-readline(prompt="Enter .Shared File Name:")
n2<-readline(prompt="Enter .Taxonomy File Name:")
n3<-readline(prompt="Enter Meta Table File Name:")

source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("phyloseq")
biocLite("DESeq2")
library(ape)
library(DESeq2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gplots)
library(lme4)
library(phangorn)
library(phyloseq)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(vegan)
library(VennDiagram)
library(shiny)


OTU = read.table(n1, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
tax = read.table(n2, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
meta=read.table(n3, header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep="\t")

row.names(OTU) = OTU$Group
OTU.clean = OTU[,-which(names(OTU) %in% c("label", "numOtus", "Group"))]
row.names(tax) = tax$OTU
tax.clean = tax[row.names(tax) %in% colnames(OTU.clean),]
tax.clean = separate(tax.clean, Taxonomy, into = c("Domain", "Phylum", 
"Class", "Order", "Family", "Genus", "Species", "Strain"), sep=";")
tax.clean = tax.clean[,-which(names(tax.clean) %in% c("Size", "Strain", "OTU"))]
OTU.clean = OTU.clean[order(row.names(OTU.clean)),]
meta = meta[order(row.names(meta)),]
meta.controls <- meta[which(meta$group=='Control'),]
meta.controls = meta.controls[order(row.names(meta)),]
meta.experimental <- meta[which(meta$group=='Experimental'),]
meta.experimental = meta.experimental[order(row.names(meta)),]
meta.day0 <- meta[which(meta$collected_date=="0"),]
meta.day28 <- meta[which(meta$collected_date=="28"),]
OTU.clean.day0 <- OTU.clean[which(meta$collection_date=="0"),]
OTU.clean.day28 <- OTU.clean[which(meta$collection_date=="28"),]
meta.day0 <- meta[which(meta$collection_date=="0"),]
meta.day28 <- meta[which(meta$collection_date=="28"),]
OTU.clean.relabund <- sweep(OTU.clean,1,rowSums(OTU.clean),"/")
rowSums(OTU.clean)
rowSums(OTU.clean.relabund)
set.seed(8765)
OTU.physeq = otu_table(as.matrix(OTU.clean), taxa_are_rows=FALSE)
tax.physeq = tax_table(as.matrix(tax.clean))
meta.physeq = sample_data(meta)
meta.physeq.control = sample_data(meta.controls)
meta.physeq.experimental= sample_data(meta.experimental)
physeq.alpha = phyloseq(OTU.physeq, tax.physeq, meta.physeq)
physeq.alpha.controls =phyloseq(OTU.physeq, tax.physeq, 
meta.physeq.control)
physeq.alpha.experimental=phyloseq(OTU.physeq, tax.physeq, 
meta.physeq.experimental)
sample_data(physeq.alpha)$shannon.physeq <- 
estimate_richness(physeq.alpha, measures="Shannon")
sample_data(physeq.alpha.controls)$shannon.physeq <- 
estimate_richness(physeq.alpha.controls, measures="Shannon")
sample_data(physeq.alpha.experimental)$shannon.physeq <- 
estimate_richness(physeq.alpha.experimental, measures="Shannon")

title = "Shannon Diversity Over Study Timecourse"
plot_richness(physeq.alpha, measures="Shannon", title = title) #FIGURE 1
dev.copy(png,'figure_1.png')
dev.off()
```

I can get the UI to present beautifully, but I'm having a rather hard time linking my code (for example, the 16s.R script that generates the "shannon1" figure) to the buttons. I know the server function has to be reactive to the "submit" function, but it also needs to be dependent upon (a) the input of the four files, (b) a selected 16S or ITS radio button, (c) the selected analysis.

Comment: This is a little broad for one question. It sounds like you actually have 3 problems: 1) how to upload data, 2) how to run R code when the user clicks a button, and 3) how to download an image. I'd start with a shiny tutorial and figure out how to do (2) with a built in dataset, then tackle (1) and (3). There are questions here that already deal with how to do them, so you should be able to figure it out. Shiny can be a handful to work with, so take it one small step at a time and you'll be fine!

Comment: Thanks for that advice!